# Mongoose string value returning undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose schema and model

```
const productSchema = new Schema<productType>({
    _id: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true,
        default: new ObjectId()
    },
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    barcode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    stock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    stockCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    addedTime: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    branchPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    categories: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
        default: []
    },
    discount: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    discountPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        default: 0
    },
    favs: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
        default: []
    },
    brand: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        },
        brandName: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    images: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
        default: []
    },
    image1: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image2: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    image3: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    image4: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    image5: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
})
export const Products = mongoose.model<productType>('products', productSchema) || mongoose.models.products
```

When I am trying to create a document with mongoose its not writing "barcode" value ("barcode" value is exist i am sure about it.) but when i am trying to create same document with mongodb library "barcode" value is not undefined its writing successfully. When i am try to find a document same for mongodb.
""
When I tried to find a document its returning undefined at "barcode" value but it is not undefined[Example data from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2O1V.png)

Mongoose database string value returning undefined